# Difference between image retrieval and image classification

Tags: image-processing, classification, svm, matlab

```
load fisheriris
xdata = meas(51:end,3:4);
group = species(51:end);
svmStruct = svmtrain(xdata,group,'showplot',true);



species = svmclassify(svmStruct,[5 2],'showplot',true)
hold on;plot(5,2,'ro','MarkerSize',12);hold off
```

The above code gives the result ---> species = 'virginica'

The species is classified as 'virginica'. This is just one image. Can this process of classification be termed as "image retrieval" ???

Or do we have to retrieve many images, in order for it to be termed as image retrieval ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Image classification: Train the model on a data set called training set and then test using a data set which is disjoint from training set (most important).

Image retrieval: Given a query image, get the "closest" image to the query image from database. Now, the term "closest" can be with respect to color, shape, texture etc. So what decides "closest" - the feature vector of the image, which user calculates according to a algorithm designed to suit his needs.

Major difference between classification and retrieval: Classification needs labels for training data, retrieval does not. Retrieval is a purely distance-based approach.

Now, moving on to your question: This would not be termed as retrieval, because it is just telling me the class of the query image, not providing me with similar images. Now you might argue that what if I classify 100 images like these and out of 100 if 50 belong to a certain class then those can be viewed as similar images. Is this correct? The answer in my view is No. Consider an example where you have to classify images having cars vs. no cars. In case of (perfect) classification, all the 50 images will surely have cars. But in the case of (perfect) retrieval, all the 50 images will have either same color cars or small/big cars etc. This is the difference.

You can say that the top retrieved image can be taken as classification result. That is possible. But again, we have very powerful classification algorithms (for example, SVM, Random forest, Boosting, Multiple-instance learning etc.) but the case is not the same with retrieval (as far as my knowledge is concerned). Therefore, if you want to perform classification, you will not take the top result of retrieval, you will always use the dedicated algorithms for classification.

To summarize, a process is called retrieval if it does not need labels and it retrieves with respect to some attribute (color, texture, shape etc.). Classification is where you need labels and it is done with respect to category (for example, cars/no cars, people/no people, natural/man-made etc.).

I hope this clarifies your concept.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. Now I am clear with the differences. @Parag